# How to manipulate video codec errors using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I want to create a video full of codec errors like this:

How can I manipulate ffmpeg parameters to create an output video like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're looking for looks like datamoshing. Give that a quick google search - it might be what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen some examples either through python script [link](https://github.com/happyhorseskull/you-can-datamosh-on-linux/blob/master/do_the_mosh.py) or through Hex Editing [link](http://datamoshing.com/2016/06/17/how-to-datamosh-videos-with-data-corruption/)